# Wordpress Queries Killing DB

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have two queries that are constantly flooding my mysql processlist causing my db to run hot:

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '1463226126' WHERE `option_name` = '_site_transient_timeout'

UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:3178:{i:1442904753;a:2:{s:23:\"wpseo_hit_sitemap_index\"
```

But for some reason I can't seem to find any documentation on how to disable them or make them run with cron.  I am using cronjobs (not wp cron) and have also tried disabling the ping with this:

```
add_filter('wpseo_allow_xml_sitemap_ping', '__return_false');
```

Do you have any thoughts on what else could be done?

Comment: Is that session data?

Comment: how many records do you have when `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = '_site_transient_timeout'`? and how big is that table?

Comment: I have 4, but for appended values (_itsec_upload_dir, _timeout_browser) ,etc